# Yfinance API for FX rates no longer working on Python

Tags: python, yfinance

I have a simple line of code that seems to no longer be working with the yfinance API.

I am 99% sure that this used to work. Could you please tell me why it does not work anymore?

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

# define GBP as the base currency
base_currency = 'GBP'

# create a list of currencies to scrape
currencies = df['Currency'].unique().tolist()

# scrape FX data for each currency against GBP
fx_data = {}
for currency in currencies:
    ticker = f"{currency}{base_currency}=X"
    fx_rate = yf.Ticker(ticker).info['regularMarketPrice']
    fx_data[currency] = fx_rate
```

The error lies with the 'fx_rate = yf.Ticker(ticker).info['regularMarketPrice']' line.

Here is a sample error message:

HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?formatted=true&lang=en-US&symbols=SGDGBP%3DX

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Yahoo Finance regularly updates their APIs and protocols, breaking all the third-party packages that try to use it.  You will have to go monitor the `yfinance` web page to watch for an updated version.

Comment: Thank you Tim. Do you know how to make the code more 'future proof'? Is there a better API you'd recommend? Sorry I'm really new to this!

Comment: Remember that `yfinance` is an open source tool that scrapes from Yahoo Finance.  Yahoo would rather make money from Yahoo Finance Plus subscriptions, so they have no incentive to be nice to a free tool exploiting their data.  If this is for a business, then you should probably sign up for one of the paid services that provide a guaranteed API.  https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/